# xslt allowed arguments in concat and normalize-space

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xpath, xquery

I was looking through some code and i saw this:

```
<xsl:variable name="newlist" select="concat(normalize-space($list), ' ')" />
```

I'm just wondering with just this info, can i safely say for sure that $list is a `string` and `normalize-space($list)` will definitely return me a `string` and the line `concat(normalize-space($list), ' ')` will definitely return me a `string` (and the last character of that string is a space?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$list` could be a string, a number, a node set, anything. The result will be a string. And yes, the last character will be a space.

For instance:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="node">
            <node>
                <subnode>string</subnode>
                <subnode>otherstring</subnode>
            </node>
        </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="string" select="concat($node,' ')"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="string-length($string)"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($string,' ')"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

returns

```
18stringotherstring
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can safely assume this will return a string but you can't say for sure that $list is a string as normalize-space will attempt to convert to a string first. eg.

```
 <xsl:value-of select="concat(normalize-space(13), ' ')"/>
```

Will work.

More info on [concat](http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/fn_concat.html) and [normalize-space](http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/fn_normalize-space.html).

Also note that this could fail if `$list` is set incorrectly, such as

```
<xsl:variable name="list" select="12 34" />
```

So you can never really safely assume it will work without seeing the rest of the code.

Comment: That's not going to work because the variable definition itself is wrong. `Unexpected token "<numeric-literal>" beyond end of expression`.

Comment: That's what I was pointing out wasn't it? It seems the OP isn't aware of other code in the XSLT file only 1 particualr line. Therefore if that invalid variable declaration (unseen) is used it is not safe to assume his code will run.